# how can we prove that the number of nodes in a minimum node-cover C* of G is greater than the number of edges in a maximum matching M* of G

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, duality-theorems, matching-theory

Define a node cover $C$ for a graph $G = (V;E)$ to be a set of nodes $C$ such that, for every edge
$(u, v)$ that belongs to $E$, $C$ contains at least one of u and v. Define a minimum node-cover of $G$ to be a
node-cover that minimizes the number of node in the node cover.

Let $|C*|$ denote the number of nodes in a minimum node-cover $C*$ of $G$, and let $|M*|$ denote
the number of edges in a maximum matching $M*$ of $G$. Prove that $|M*|  \leq |C*|$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that each edge $(u,v) \in M*$ is incident to a vertex $w_{(u,v)} \in C*$ by the definition of $C*$. Moreover if you consider two different edges $(u_{1},v_{1}), (u_{2},v_{2}) \in M*$, then $w_{(u_{1},v_{1})} \neq w_{(u_{2},v_{2})}$. Otherwise both edges in the matching are incident in $w_{(u_{1},v_{1})} = w_{(u_{2},v_{2})}$, and it is a contradiction with the fact that $M*$ is a matching.

This shows that for each edge in $M*$ one can find a different vertex in $C*$, in other words, we have found an injection from $M*$ to $C*$. It shows that $|M*| \leq |C*|$.

Comment: You mean the other way around $|M^*| \le |C^*|$ though, correct?

Comment: @Mike  Exactly! Edited, xD

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused by your notation of a vertex [w(u,v)]. Isn't (u,v) an edge, how are we using it to show a vertex?

Comment: @varshR, Yes, $w_{(u,v)}$ is a vertex. When you consider an edge $(u, v)$, at least one of its points is a vertex in $C*$ we don't know if it is $u$ or $v$, then we can denote it by $w_{(u,v)}$. If both vertices are in $C*$, one can just choose one to be $w_{(u,v)}$.